# jquery ajax call in UserControl asp.net returns error "Internal Server Error"

Tags: ajax, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

I have a UserControl (.ascx) and I want to do an Ajax control on the email.

this is my ajax call inside the file Login.ascx

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Login.aspx/CheckEmail",
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{email:'"+email+"'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("We returned: " + data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

and this is my webMethod in file **Login.aspx.cs**

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static string CheckEmail(string email)
    {
        return "it worked";
    }
```

Now, I always have the Error message that is telling me: Internal Server Error
[image]

What is wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't place the WebMethod inside user controls, you have to place it inside a page or inside a service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I put the WebMethod inside an aspx page like Login.aspx/CheckEmail it should work? because now the errorThrown is "Internal server Error" maybe there is another error?

Comment: Question edited,however thank you because the error is changed ;)